# выборка уникальных значений из DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

есть такой DataFrame `df`:

```
      topic   topic_id  
0     тема 1        39   
1     тема 1        39   
2     тема 2        15    
3     тема 2        15   
4     тема 1        39   
5     тема 3        42
```

мне надо сделать новый словарь с уникальными значениями, где ключ будет`topic_id`, а значение `topic`.

мне нужно написать код на питоне, аналогичный этому:

```
<?php
foreach($df as $item){
    $array[$item["topic_id"]] = $item["topic"]
}
?>
```

т.е. нужно получить простой словарь в виде

```
{39: 'тема 1', 15: 'тема 2', 42: 'тема 3'}
```

откуда берётся имеющийся DataFrame:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**db)

df = pd.read_sql("QUERY STRING", cnx)
df2 = pd.read_sql("QUERY STRING", cnx)

cnx.close()

df = pd.merge(df, df2, how='outer')
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе словарь/data set который хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: результат у вас не "простой список", а простой словарь¶ Интересная модель языка у вас: из mysql прочитать dataframe можете, не зная что словарь и спискок это разные типы в Питоне :)

Comment: я недавно начал его изучать, не привык ещё ко всем типам питона. буду пока что называть всё массивами - не прогадаю)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), чтобы избавиться от строк дупликатов в Pandas.DataFrame:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    topic  topic_id
0  тема 1        39
1  тема 1        39
2  тема 2        15
3  тема 2        15
4  тема 1        39
5  тема 3        42

In [3]: df = df.drop_duplicates()

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
    topic  topic_id
0  тема 1        39
2  тема 2        15
5  тема 3        42
```

в качестве словаря:

```
In [20]: df.drop_duplicates().set_index('topic_id')['topic'].to_dict()
Out[20]: {39: 'тема 1', 15: 'тема 2', 42: 'тема 3'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Почему не?:

```
 = {value:key for key, value in df.items()}
```

---

Если вам нужно по value получить key и при этом value нехешируемый то самый простой путь(если исключить написание своего маппера) это следующея функция:

```
def get_key(df, tmpl):
    for key, value in df.items():
        if value == tmpl:
            return key
    raise KeyError('Key not found')
```

Comment: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed. когда я пробовал с update я получал такую же ошибку.

Comment: хреново. А откуда вы берете словарь?

Comment: Также, зачем вам словарь? Чтобы получить topic_id имея topic?

Comment: я делаю несколько sql запросов, после объединяю df = pd.merge(df, df2, how='outer'), вот с этим df я и пытаюсь работать.
да, мне нужны уникальные соответствия id и названия тем из того массива данных что я получаю

Answer (score 0):

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'topic': ['тема 1', 'тема 1', 'тема 2', 'тема 2', 'тема 1', 'тема 3'], 'topic_id': [39, 39, 15, 15, 39, 49]})
```

У DataFrame есть метод to_dict(), но ключами он делает индекс. Т.е. нам нужно колонку 'topic_id' сделать индексом:

```
>> df.set_index('topic_id').to_dict()
{'topic': {39: 'тема 1', 15: 'тема 2', 49: 'тема 3'}}
```

Чтобы получить нужный словарь:

```
>> df.set_index('topic_id').to_dict()['topic']
{39: 'тема 1', 15: 'тема 2', 49: 'тема 3'}
```